# Kusto query could not be parsed

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have SecurityLog with fields like DstIP_s and want to display records matching my trojanDst table

```
let trojanDst = datatable (DstIP_s:string)
    [    "1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3"
];
SecurityLog |
| join trojanDst  on DstIP_s
```

I am getting **query could not be parsed**  error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query you posted has a redundant pipe (`|`) before the `join`.

From an efficiency standpoint, make sure the left side of the `join` is the smaller one, as suggested here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/best-practices#join-operator

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment. As [@Yoni L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55636336/5070879) pointed the problem is doubled  pipe operator.

---

For anyone with SQL background `join` may be a bit counterintuitive(in reality it is `kind=innerunique`):

[JOIN operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/joinoperator):

> **kind unspecified, kind=innerunique**
>
> Only one row from the left side is matched for each value of the on
>   key. The output contains a row for each match of this row with rows
>   from the right.
>
> **Kind=inner**
>
> There's a row in the output for every combination of matching rows
>   from left and right.

```
let t1 = datatable(key:long, value:string)  
[
1, "a",  
1, "b"  
];
let t2 = datatable(key:long, value:string)  
[  
1, "c", 
1, "d"  
];
t1| join t2 on key;
```

Output:

```
┌─────┬───────┬──────┬────────┐
│ key │ value │ key1 │ value1 │
├─────┼───────┼──────┼────────┤
│   1 │ a     │    1 │ c      │
│   1 │ a     │    1 │ d      │
└─────┴───────┴──────┴────────┘
```

**[Demo](https://portal.loganalytics.io/Demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoMVSwVUhJLAHCpJxUjezUSquc%2FLx0HYWyxJzSVKvikqLMvHRNBQVermheLkMdBaVEJR0QD8RMUgKxYq15uXJAJhkRbRLMgGSgWRBWCtyoEsMahaz8zDyQefl5CkBjgIK8XAA6T%2BPyrAAAAA%3D%3D&timespan=P1D)**

---

SQL style `JOIN` version:

```
let t1 = datatable(key:long, value:string)  
[
1, "a",  
1, "b"  
];
let t2 = datatable(key:long, value:string)  
[  
1, "c", 
1, "d"  
];
t1| join kind=inner t2 on key;
```

Output:

```
┌─────┬───────┬──────┬────────┐
│ key │ value │ key1 │ value1 │
├─────┼───────┼──────┼────────┤
│   1 │ b     │    1 │ c      │
│   1 │ a     │    1 │ c      │
│   1 │ b     │    1 │ d      │
│   1 │ a     │    1 │ d      │
└─────┴───────┴──────┴────────┘
```

**[Demo](https://portal.loganalytics.io/Demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoMVSwVUhJLAHCpJxUjezUSquc%2FLx0HYWyxJzSVKvikqLMvHRNBQVermheLkMdBaVEJR0QD8RMUgKxYq15uXJAJhkRbRLMgGSgWRBWCtyoEsMahaz8zDyF7My8FNvMvLzUIpDR%2BUCB1EqgPAB%2FytuytQAAAA%3D%3D&timespan=P1D)**

Answer (score 1):

There are many join types in KQL such as innerunique, inner, leftouter, rightouter, fullouter, anti and more. here you can find the [full list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/joinoperator)